# Aligning div overlay on percentage width element

Tags: css, layout, alignment, overlay, liquid

I'm building a "staff" page with a liquid, four-column layout. I've placed a div element, absolutely positioned on top of the photo of each staff member to act as a button/link. My problem is that when I align this overlay div to bottom:0 and right:0 I will get the occasional 1 pixel gap between the image and the overlay as I resize the window. It seems this is a function of some sort of round-off error.

I've searched this site and others for help on this, but I haven't found this issue explicitly discussed anywhere. Any insights are greatly appreciated.

The page in question can be seen here: 
[communicationdesign.com/cwt-beta/about.html](http://communicationdesign.com/cwt-beta/about.html)

Resize the window to see the occasional error/gap...

Here is the relevant markup:

```
<div class="staff-block">
    <div class="staff-photo">
        <a href="gruber.html"><img src="img/gruber.jpg" class="portrait" /></a>
        <a href="gruber.html">
            <div class="plus-link">
                <div class="plus-sign">&#43;</div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="caption">
        <a href="gruber.html">Drew Gruber</a><br /><span class="job-title">Executive Director</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.staff-block {
    position: relative;
    width: 22.3%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ffc;
    margin-right: 3.5%;
}
.staff-photo{
    position: relative;
}
.staff-photo img, .board-photo img, .bio-photo img {
    width: 100%;
}
.portrait {
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    transition: .5s ease;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.plus-link {
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.plus-sign {
  background-color: rgba(255,204,78,0.8);
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 4px 8px 6px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an occupational hazard when using percentages. You could use a hack like this:

```
.staff-photo{
    overflow: hidden;
}

.plus-link {
  background-color: rgba(255,204,78,0.8); // color on the plus sign parent 
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5px; // position it over the edge
  right: -5px;
  padding: 0 5px 5px 0; // and correct the extra space
}

.plus-sign {
  background-color: transparent; // or remove bg color
}
```